# Dynamic Programming - Minimum number of coins in C

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have looked through various questions on the site and I haven't managed to find anything which implements this by the following reasoning (so I hope this isn't a duplicate).

The problem I'm trying to solve via a C program is the following:

> As the programmer of a vending machine controller your are required to compute the minimum number of coins that make up the required change to give back to customers. An efficient solution to this problem takes a dynamic programming approach, starting off computing the number of coins required for a 1 cent change, then for 2 cents, then for 3 cents, until reaching the required change and each time making use of the prior computed number of coins. Write a program containing the function `ComputeChange()`, that takes a list of valid coins and the required change. This program should repeatedly ask for the required change from the console and call `ComputeChange()` accordingly. It should also make use of “caching”, where any previously computed intermediate values are retained for subsequent look-up.

After looking around online to find how others have solved it, I found the following example applied with pennies, nickels and dimes:

[image]

Which I tried to base my code upon. But first of all, my code isn't halting, and secondly, I'm not sure if I'm incorporating the *caching* element mentioned in the rubric above. (I'm not really sure how I need to go about that part).

Can anyone help find the flaws in my code?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int computeChange(int[],int,int);
int min(int[],int);

int main(){
    int cur[]={1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200};
    int n = sizeof(cur)/sizeof(int);
    int v;

    printf("Enter a value in euro cents: ");
    scanf("%d", &v);

    printf("The minimum number of euro coins required is %d", computeChange(cur, v, n));

    return 0;
}

int computeChange(int cur[], int v, int n){
    if(v < 0)
        return -1;
    else if(v == 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        int possible_mins[n], i;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            possible_mins[i]=computeChange(cur, v-cur[i], n);
        }
        return 1+min(possible_mins, n);
    };
}

int min(int a[], int n){
    int min = INT_MAX, i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if((i>=0) && (a[i]< min))
            min = a[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have, but since `computeChange()` is being used recursively, it's got a bit confusing. I'm debugging it again at the moment.

Comment: So... if you put a breakpoint in computeChange(), it is continually getting hit, ie. runaway recursion?

Comment: I tried inputting the number 1 and the array `possible_mins` had the elements 683967304 and -858993469 in the first execution of the `else`, which isn't a good sign....

Comment: Owait - it's not initialized at entry to the 'else'

Comment: Nice job on a really well formatted question

Comment: @MartinJames what d'you mean?

Comment: You probably need to return `INT_MAX` instead of `-1` when `v < 0` in your `computeChange` function.

Comment: yes, I agree with Ian Abbott here on returning INT_MAX when v < 0.

Comment: @IanAbbott I changed that, but I still got those big numbers :(

Comment: Do you expect that `possible_mins` will be 'shared' between different recursive calls of `computeChange()?` Because it won't. Nor do VLAs, as I think @MartinJames was saying, have all of their elements initialised to 0.

Comment: How would I do that? In the else clause?

Comment: Do what, 0-initialise it? If so, well, it's only scoped within the `else` clause, so yes, and `memset` is the usual way to zero-out things.

Comment: I believe that with the given currencies, a greedy algorithm is guaranteed to get the right answer and be much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's supplied `Change()` algorithm incurs *lots* of recursion, even with the `if(v < 0) return INT_MAX;` correction.  So much recursion that even small-ish values take millions of recursive calls.

A simple improvement is to "cache" the best solution found so far.  Then when an intermediate solution is already worse than the best, no need to continue that path.

```
int computeChange(int cur[], int v, int n, int count_now, int *bestcount) {
  if (count_now >= *bestcount) {
    return INT_MAX;
  }
  if (v < 0) {
    return INT_MAX;
  }
  if (v == 0) {
    *bestcount = count_now;
    return 0;
  }

  int min_count = INT_MAX;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int count = computeChange(cur, v - cur[i], n, count_now+1, bestcount);
    if (count < min_count) {
      min_count = count + 1;
    }
  }
  return min_count;
}

  int bc = INT_MAX;
  computeChange(cur, v, n, 0, &bc));
```

A secondary improvement is to attempt using large coins first

```
 // int count = computeChange(cur, v - cur[i], n, count_now+1, bestcount);
 int count = computeChange(cur, v - cur[n-i-1], n, count_now+1, bestcount);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the below is the code snippet for your problem using memoization and dynamic programming. The complexity is O(Val*numTypesofCoins).

In the end, change[val] will give you the min number of coins for val.

```
int change [MAX];
int cur[]={1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200};
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
int val= //whatever user enters to get the num of coins required.

for (i=0; i <= val; i++) {
    change[i] = INT_MAX;
}
for (i=0; i < n; i++) { // change for the currency coins should be 1.
    change[cur[i]] = 1;
}

for (i=1; i <= val; i++) {
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int coins = 0;
    if (change[i] != INT_MAX) { // Already got in 2nd loop
        continue;
    }
    for (j=0; j < n; j++) {
        if (cur[j] > i) { // coin value greater than i, so break.
            break;
        }
        coins = 1 + change[i - cur[j]]; 
        if (coins < min) {
            min = coins;
        }
    }
    change[i] = min;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the sum of say x and the coins of denominations say `a1, a2, a3, a4..`(in decreasing order)
then the answer is simply->
`x/a1+(x%a2)/a3+((x%a2)%a3)/a4+...`
This should hopefully give the answer